# What is the proper way to use JADE, attribute "placeholder" and an input field?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm building a form with the jade engine in a node.js environment and started to think of the best practice (AKA less code) to combine the "placeholder" and "value" attribute in an input element.

```
form(action="/add" method="POST")
    input(placeholder="Your name" name="username" value="#{username}")
    input(placeholder="Your title" name="title"  value="#{title}")
```

However, sometimes #{username} will be populated and sometimes it will not. If it's not populated it will be substituted to "undefined" by jade and my "placeholder" attribute never kicks in.

So, is there a setting to jade so all undefined variables is returning an empty string or a similar solution?

Imagine that the form has about 10-15 fields and I hope that I din't have to create a conditional check on each input element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input(placeholder="Your name" name="username" value=username)
```

Comment: Does this solve the problem that it won't be populated sometimes?

Comment: If it won't be populated (which means it will be undefined), then `value` won't even exist. So yeah, I think it solves it. The issue is that `#{...}` is like an explicit conversion to a string, but it's not what you want here in the first place.

Comment: But the value of attribute is always a string. I don't understand why `#{}` behaves differently form a normal assignment of a variable with a string content.

Comment: Value of attribute is **not** always a string. It can be boolean (i.e. `required`).

Comment: Also, we are talking about javascript variable here, and javascript variable is not always a string. Jade can also recognize "null"/"undefined"/"false" (value won't be present), and "true" (gets expanded to "value"="value", useful for checkboxes).